# A program function to find the sum of the rows and columns in a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

I've got the program body, most of my errors are in my function. I've tried fixing it but i can't change the data types.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumrow (int matrix);
int sumcol (int matrix);

int main () {

int matrix [3][4] = { {5, 7, 4, 8}, {6, 8, 2, 4}, {2, 7, 9, 6} };
int sum;

sumrow = matrix[3][4];
```

[Error] assignment of function 'int sumrow(int)'
This data type error makes no sense to me and I can't change it.
[Error] cannot convert 'int' to 'int(int)' in assignment

```
sumcol = matrix[3][4];
```

[Error] assignment of function 'int sumcol(int)'
[Error] cannot convert 'int' to 'int(int)' in assignment
The errors here are identical and I am probably calling the error incorrectly.

```
return 0;
}


int sumrow (int matrix){
int i, j, sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) 
        {
            sum = sum + matrix[i][j] ;
```

[Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
Both functions have the same error and I think it's because of the variables i used.

```
        }
    }
return printf("Sum of the %d row is = %d\n", sum);
}


int sumcol (int matrix){

int i, j, sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            sum = sum + matrix[i][j];
```

[Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
I don't know how to fix this error.

```
        }
    }
return printf("Sum of the %d column is = %d\n", sum);
 }
```

Comment: `int sumcol (int matrix);` and `sumcol = matrix[3][4];`: Is `sumcol` supposed to be a function or an `int`?  Same question with `int sumrow (int matrix);`.

Comment: You accessing memory outside the array here: `sumrow = matrix[3][4];` and `sumcol = matrix[3][4];`.

Comment: `int sumrow (int matrix)`  should be `int sumrow (int matrix[3][4])`  and the call should be `sumrow(matrix)`

Answer (score 1):

The subroutine should be defined to take a 2D array instead of a single int.  Note that you can leave the leftmost dimension empty.

```
int sumrow (int matrix[][4]){
    int i, j, sum = 0;  
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    etc...
```

And you need to call it by passing the array, not one element:

```
int sum = sumrow(matrix);
```

The return value of sumrow should be the sum that you calculated:

```
return sum;
```